# Moving an object with vector3.MoveTowards

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, device, gameobject

I am working on a game app with Unity. I have an issue when it comes to move a GameObject .

In my game, when the player swipes up with his device, the GameObject moves from a point A to B, and when he swipes down, it goes from B to A.

I wrote a C# script with the game logic, but I have an issue when it comes to this.

The problem is that the GameObject moves instantly from A to B.

Here is the code line I use to move my GameObject :

```
transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards (PositionA,PositionB,Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

`speed` is a float with a value of 10.0f.

I would like my GameObject to move slowly to point A to B. And despite the changes on speed value, nothing change, it's still moving instantly.

How can I fix that? (I tried with `Vector3.Lerp` and I had the same results).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Vector3.MoveTowards` takes the current position, the target position, and the step, but it seems like your first argument here is origin of the move, rather than current position. Normally you'd do this something like this, in your `Update()`:

`transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.localPosition, PositionB, Time.deltaTime * speed);`

with the current position as the first argument.

Comment: when i wrote your line, it's moving smoothly at first and then instantly go to position B (at 50% of the distance). Also, when i swipe down, it doesn't want to return to point A.

Comment: @Ophélia Hm? I don't have Unity installed, so I can't test right now, but it should work. Are you changing the transform position somewhere else, or something? And for moving towards A, you'd have to change what target it's moving towards.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to use `MoveTowards`:

```
void Update()
{
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, PositionB, step);
}
```

[LearnMore](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)