# How can I move an object towards another object in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cube that I want to always be moving towards my player. I've tried several solutions over the course of a few hours, but none of them have worked. My current script looks like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class fol : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    public GameObject Player;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        Vector3.MoveTowards(Player.transform.position.x, Player.transform.position.y, Player.transform.position.z, 1);
    }
}
```

This script is a child of the object that I want to move towards my player.

Nothing has ever compiled. The only error for this script is:

> Assets/fol.cs(16,11): error CS1501: No overload for method MoveTowards takes 4 arguments

So, once I remove the 1 it ends up with:

> Assets/fol.cs(16,11): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for UnityEngine.Vector3.MoveTowards(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, float)' has some invalid arguments

and

> Assets/fol.cs(16,49): error CS1503: Argument #1 cannot convert float expression to type UnityEngine.Vector3

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them have worked"? Please more descriptive about what the code in the question currently does.

Comment: @Ruzihm Nothing has ever compiled. The only error for this script is Assets/fol.cs(16,11): error CS1501: No overload for method `MoveTowards' takes `4' arguments, so once I remove the 1 it ends up with Assets/fol.cs(16,11): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Vector3.MoveTowards(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, float)' has some invalid arguments and Assets/fol.cs(16,49): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `float' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3'

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and moved the errors into the question. See the answer linked at the top of this question's page for how to use `MoveTowards` and how to assign the result to the cube's position.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MoveTowards` the first position given should be the position of the object you need to move, then the second should be the position of the goal, with the third argument being the movement increment. As @Ruzihm suggests this is a duplicate of [Moving an object with Vector3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489102/moving-an-object-with-vector3-movetoward) and you'll find a great info to resolve this there. Also check out the [unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html).